# Clear an activity on moving from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

i have an home activity with icons at bottom navigation bar. On clicking the icons it moves to respective fragments. But the problem is the home activity stacks over all the fragments. What might be the problem here.

I tried finish(); after calling the fragment. But that closes all activities and goes to main activity. I need help.

Main Activity->HomeActivity-> attendance fragment

This is the home activity
[Home Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kkob.png)

On clicking the Attendance fragment below
[Attendance fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYkUx.png)

Here is the code of home activity

```
 public class FHome extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static Activity fa;

        private Toolbar toolbar;

        private ListView listView;

        public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

        public static String SEL_DAY;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_fhome);
            setupUIViews();
            initToolbar();
            setupListView();
            fa = this;

            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                    findViewById(R.id.navigation);

            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                    (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.action_item1:
                                    selectedFragment = FAttendance.newInstance();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.action_item2:
                                    selectedFragment = FPost.newInstance();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.action_item3:
                                    selectedFragment = FUpdate.newInstance();
                                    break;
                            }
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                            transaction.commit();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

            //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, FPost.newInstance());
            transaction.commit();


        }
```

Help me out :(

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s handle only dynamically created `Fragment`s. If you have `View`s, or a static `<fragment>`, defined in the `frame_layout` in the `activity_fhome` layout, that `replace()` transaction will not remove them. Your new `Fragment` will get stacked on top.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the problem. Can you give me a solution? @MikeM.

Comment: Load your home screen in a dynamic `Fragment`, too, so it will be replaced by that transaction. If that screen is a `<fragment>`, then you just need to load that one dynamically in `onCreate()`. If that screen is regular `View`s, create a `Fragment` for them, and load that dynamically.